# load jquery after live chat plugin

Tags: php, jquery

I have a site with a live chat plugin which I have virtually no control over. I want to hide the pop up when the page loads so I have have my own button to toggle the visibility.

My toggle works, but my .hide() doesn't. Its because the live chat loads itself before the body tag so even though my jQuery is just before the body in my code, this loads after and changes the display style itself.

Is there ant way to insert and tell my line of code to load last?

Comment: Have you tried `window.onload` event?

Answer (score 0):

[`$(document).ready(callback)`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) executes as soon as everything on the DOM is loaded. Just wrap it around your hide function.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#popup").hide();
});
```